# How to separate a string from another string and turn it into a comma separated list

Tags: list

If my string is-
''Felix Underhalm'' and I want to turn into...
list = ['F', 'E', 'L', 'I', 'X']

How should I do it?

Comment: What is your actual programming language?  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: its python. No, I have tried almost nothing yet.